# How much time does it take to reduce belly fat?

Tags: weight-loss, cardio, abdominals, body-fat, bellyfat

I read lot of questions on reducing belly fat in this forum. I am also suffering from large fat around my abdomen. i have started exercise (weight training + cardio) and leading with healthy food habits as indicated in these questions.

How much time should i expect in reduction of substantial fat as i don't want to look at mirror everyday :) ?

Comment: it depends... if you could control your diet and train consistently you will be able to see a result in a month or less... But some people who train alot but would not control their diet will take much more longer time to reduce substantial fats.

Comment: You're right @JieLiang, a very important issue is dieting!!

Comment: as others said, it depends. I lost a lot of belly fat by using bicycle for my commute for a year as I turned into a student. The effect of biking is great and is fun too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also had the same problem, the best way to lose fat is by performing intensive exercises. I prepared myself mentally to change:

1. The bad habits
2. No more fast-food, hamburgers etc...
3. Lifestyle/clubbing,
4. Sleep soon, wake up soon!

AFTER 3 months I saw some changes, but this depends on how much fat you have on your belly, how intensive you train, and how motivated you are.

I will sum up some sports which could help you to achieve this very fast.

- Muay Thai;
- Mixed Martial Arts;
- Running;

NICE TO DO:

> Try to do a lot of sit-ups exercises, this helps a lot. And jogging in the nature, just by yourself with some nice beats on your iPod.

Hope this will help.

Comment: martial arts? it will help but i dont think that is a good way. jogging, sit up, leg lift will be much better to reduce the belly fats then taking up in martial arts course.

Comment: Yes, Martial Arts for grappling and other techniques you need to develop your abs. I lost a lot of belly fat by joining my local MMA club.

Comment: MMA will help but i dont think that is the answer he is looking for. Is better to describe to him the exercise that will help him with his belly fats.

Comment: if he joins an MMA club and starts to train hard, and looses belly fat. He can also ask the trainer/coach at the club, he'll help him further.

Comment: This website is created so we could help each other by giving tips on training. Not asking him to go look for a trainer instead. If you look through the older post. You can see all the post giving guide or tips on how to train. None have ask ppl to look for trainer or join MMA. I am not saying MMA is bad.

Comment: I had the same problem, and in my answer I explained how I got rid of it. If he joins a club, there will be a supervisor who can help him increasing his limits to a higher level. In a club you must follow the commands of the trainer instead of showing mercy to yourself after 5 minutes of intensive training and giving up. To adapt sport in your daily life you have to be motivated, and again a good coach can help you with that in a very short period. I explain what I experienced, if you hate MMA or you love it that's your business @JieLiang

Comment: Think u dont understand what i am saying. I never say i hate or love MMA i am neutral. I am not good at explaining myself. So let it be.

Comment: Okay, I hope my posts will help

Comment: Thank you Jie Liang and SirProgrammer for putting comments in this context. Well I am working guy (software/sitting job) so i spend daily 2 hours for workout (weight training and cardiovascular) and have improved the quality of intake food as well. The most important thing for me is to maintain the consistency to get results.

Comment: Is this some sort of joke? Doing situps to reduce bellyfat? As in spot-reduction?

Comment: To add to Alec's incredulity. Spot reduction does not work. If you train your 'core' without altering your diet you end up (broadly speaking) with a strong core under a layer of fat. To reduce that fat you have to reduce total body fat, by careful moderation of calorie intake and exercise.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience loosing fat quickly at the expense of muscle mass is doable but is an extremely bad idea. Better aim for a moderate speed of 1% minimum and 2% maximum of your body mass per month of fat made.  That way you keep your muscle mass and you wont bounce back that easily.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your dedication and the time spent on doing some exercises. i was weighing almost 94kgs in 2013, i started exercising at a gym near my home i used to walk to and fro and work out for 60mins before breakfast. and sticked to meal plan or diet with no alcohol and meat. i am now 78 kgs. it almost took 6 months to be at 80.