# How to reduce my BIG BELLY into SMALL within 3 to 4 weeks

Tags: weight-loss, abdominals, body-fat, bellyfat, stomach

I have big belly in my stomach, i'm going to get married in a month. So i need to reduce my stomach in home remedies.. Please guys help me with giving some tips. Surely i will follow.

Thanks,
Kumara Guru Barar.

Comment: There are a lot of questions on the topic of fat reduction on this site, you should read them first and then ask for clarification if there are questions left, we don't need to go over and over the same topic again.

Comment: Also related [How much time does it take to reduce belly fat?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/6679/3941)